# Flutter change reverseTransitionDuration of PageRoute via state

Tags: flutter, state, transition, duration

I've made several attempts to change the `reverseTransitionDuration` of a `PageRoute` / `ModalRoute` without success. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart) of `ModalRoute` there is a setter for `offstage` at line 1457.

```
bool get offstage => _offstage;
  bool _offstage = false;
  set offstage(bool value) {
    if (_offstage == value) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      _offstage = value;
    });
    _animationProxy!.parent = _offstage ? kAlwaysCompleteAnimation : super.animation;
    _secondaryAnimationProxy!.parent = _offstage ? kAlwaysDismissedAnimation : super.secondaryAnimation;
    changedInternalState();
  }
```

Could a similar approach be used for the `reverseTransitionDuration` property.

```
@override
Duration get reverseTransitionDuration => _reverseTransitionDuration;
Duration _reverseTransitionDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 500);
set reverseTransitionDuration(Duration value){
  if(_reverseTransitionDuration != value){
    setState(() {
      _reverseTransitionDuration = value;
      controller.reverseDuration = value;
    });
    changedInternalState();
  }
}
```

Then this function can be called via an `InheritedWidget` containing this `ModalRoute`.

Before I refactor a custom `ModalRoute` again it would be helpful to know if it is possible to change this property in this way and therefore programatically change the reverseDuration of a route before it is popped.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes this works in principle. Some things to take into account.

`changedInternalState();` is not relevant and may cause additional problems with unacknowledged late variables for certain Route types. Set state will work fine without this inclusion.

Remember a few things. The getter, `reverseTransitionDuration` is used by `CreateAnimationController` but not referenced again by the Route's `AnimationController`. Therefore it is necessary to also update the controller's `reverseDuration` property (shown in the question).

Theoretically this should apply to every property of `PageRoute` / `ModalRoute`. However if getting properties via `didChangeNext` and `didChangePrevious`, remember that these methods will only be called when that previous route or next route changes not when state is changed on those routes. If a property of those routes changes via `setState`, the method will not be called again and this is where a `changeNotifier` would come back into play for Listening to a notifier of the nextRoute or previousRoute.

Yes I should have tried this before asking but I'd been pulling my hair out over the number of refactors already.

Hopefully that helps anyone else who wished to know how to modify properties of a `Route` via state.